# Can someone be arrested for having an extremely offensive google play games id?

Tags: internet, police, india

Suppose the person have put an offensive name like jihadijohn in this form : j1had1john1s1s will he/she get in trouble with police? If yes then how will it be report it?
answer according to india law

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not. There was a provision, [section 66a](http://www.itlaw.in/section-66a-punishment-for-sending-offensive-messages-through-communication-service-etc/) of the 2008 Information Technology Act, which criminalized sending "any information that is grossly offensive or has menacing character" by computer, under which one might *imagine* pressing a claim. That law was [struck down](http://www.itlaw.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/sec66A-judgment.pdf) as unconstitutional, because it "infringes the fundamental right to free speech and expression", which is guaranteed by Article 19(1)(a) of the Indian Constitution. Thus "it is not open to the State to curtail freedom of speech to promote the general public interest". It was important to the court's decision that offensiveness is highly subjective.